# Clarification on list subsetting within a function

Tags: r

Please see the following code.
I try to add functions which are not same to `func_list` .
However, `func_list[[1]]` and `func_list[[2]]` show same value.
I want the result that `func_list[[1]](1) = 2`, but it fails.
Please tell me where I should correct my code.

```
func_list = list()

for (k in 1:2) {
  z= k
  func_list[[k]] = function(y, zz = z) {y + zz}
}

a1 = 2
a1 = 3
e1 = func_list[[1]](1)
e2 = func_list[[2]](1)
```

Comment: The for loop assigns 1 to z in the first iteration and 2 in the second, overwriting it

Answer (score 4):

This is a common mistake. The reference to `z` (from `zz = z`) is not made at assignment: it is done "lazily" when needed. This means that R does not try to resolve `z` until you call it in the assignment to `e1`. It will first check for previous arguments named `z` (and default to that if found). Then it will check in the calling namespace/environment, which in this case is the global environment. Since the `z` is defined within the `for` loop and persists in the global environment, then it is found and used. Of course, as PabloRod suggested, the value stored in `z` is the one that was last assigned to it: the value 2.

Side note: if you `rm(z)`, you'll see:

```r
rm(z)
e1 = func_list[[1]](1)
# Error in func_list[[1]](1) : object 'z' not found
```

Indicating that it had previously found it in the current environment.

One thing to realize is that functions are not just "formals" (arguments) and body, but a function is technically a "closure" that includes with it the enclosing environment. You can see this when you run

```r
environment(func_list[[1]])
# <environment: R_GlobalEnv>
```

meaning that outside of the namespace between the two curly braces that enclose the function's body, the next namespace searched for things is this one, `R_GlobalEnv`. Okay, let's try something else:

```r
func_list = list()

for (k in 1:2) {
  z= k
  func_list[[k]] = local({ z = k; function(y, zz = z) {y + zz}; })
}

e1 = func_list[[1]](1)
e2 = func_list[[2]](1)
e1
# [1] 2
e2
# [1] 3
environment(func_list[[1]])
# <environment: 0x000000001b51adf8>
```

First, note that your `e1` and `e2` are (I believe) what you expect. Second, the environment immediately surrounding your `func_list[[1]]` is no longer the global environment. In this case, it happens to be a temporary environment instantiated by [`local`](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/base/versions/3.6.1/topics/eval) (which *"creates a new, empty environment"*). In this environment, we define `z = k` and then define the function, and this environment-with-a-function is returned, stored within `func_list`.

Another way to do this that bypasses the need for `local` (and, by the way, is strictly required if you ever get into dynamically creating [`shiny`](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/shiny/index.html) reactive objects) is to do this instead:

```r
func_list2 <- lapply(1:2, function(k) function(y, zz = k) {y + zz})
e1 = func_list2[[1]](1)
e2 = func_list2[[2]](1)
e1
# [1] 2
e2
# [1] 3
environment(func_list2[[1]])
# <environment: 0x000000001b536280>
environment(func_list2[[2]])
# <environment: 0x000000001b536088>
```

since each time the anonymous function (`function(k) ...`) is run, it is given its own temporary environment.

After all this, it might be useful to read a better-organized discussions of namespaces, environments, and their search order, such as http://adv-r.had.co.nz/Environments.html.

Comment: I appreciate for your kindly explanations!I will study the details  of namespaces, environments.